# Executing graphQL in disconnected mode

Tags: jss

I am creating a JSS application in code first approach, so I always test the components in disconnected mode. As I have proper route files, all the pages are working as expected in the disconnected mode.

But we have a requirement to use the graphQL in one of the component to fetch a folder and it's child items. So I Implemented the component to fetch content using graphQL, I did create a similar content and folder structure in the jss app under .\data\content\ but while testing query returns null/empty.

Query works in connected mode and integrated mode, but we would like to continue in disconnected mode for a while. So is there a way to run the graphQL in disconnected mode.? like how we are running the other pages and components using yml definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible out of the box in version 11.0,
You can try to mock the data.

From the JSS website:

[Using Sitecore GraphQL with GraphQL tooling](https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/graphql/graphql-overview)

Many kinds of GraphQL tools (such as eslint-plugin-graphql to validate queries at build time, or graphql-tools to create a disconnected mock GraphQL API